# Seperable ODE derivation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Looking for some help in solving the following seperable ODE,

$$\frac{d u }{d y } + 2yu = 0 $$

So my attempt at separating the variable gives,

$$\frac{d u }{d  y \ }  = -2yu  $$

$$\frac{d u }{u } = -2ydy $$

$$\ln u = -y^2+ c $$

the final answer to this solution is $u = Ce^{-y^2}$n but I am not sure how to get this result

Comment: You are so close ! (but don't use the $\partial$ symbol to denote ordinary differentials).

Comment: so where do I need to change that?

Comment: Hem, where it appears (-ed)

Comment: Edited your post please check if it still captures your initial question. As @YvesDaoust said you should write $\dfrac{d u}{d y}$ instead of $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ as (I assume that) $u$ is only a function of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there.  You have
$$
    \ln u = -y^2 + c
$$
To isolate $u$, you have to undo the ln.  The exponential function is its inverse:
$$
    u = e^{-y^2 + c} = e^c e^{-y^2}
$$
Now let $C = e^c$.